# How to get Unetbootin to recognize mounted USB drive?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, iso, unetbootin

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and every time I try to write an Ubuntu ISO image to a disk so I can install it, Unetbootin says `/dev/sdb1` isn't mounted. But Ubuntu mounts the drive automatically when it's inserted, right? What can I do to make Unetbootin recognize the drive is mounted?

Comment: here is a nice trick! to foll unetbootin

[how-do-i-use-unetbootin-to-make-a-bootable-windows-usb-installer][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162174/how-do-i-use-unetbootin-to-make-a-bootable-windows-usb-installer

Comment: None of the answers filed to this question solve the issue. Have you managed to get over this?

Comment: I can't add an answer, but deleting all files from my USB (even hidden ones, found with `ctrl+h`) helped unetbootin find it, I didn't even have to reboot it.

Comment: Creating a temp directory `/mnt/temp` and mounting manually `sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt/temp` did the trick for me, where sdc is your drive name.

Answer (score 48):

It's possible, as [beeju](https://askubuntu.com/users/55329/beeju) has [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/134563/22949), that you just need to manually mount the drive. However, you are correct--usually, Ubuntu will automatically mount a drive when it is attached or powered on.

There are two common situations where the problem you've described occurs:

1. Technically, drives are not mounted. Volumes (i.e., partitions) are mounted. If there is no partition on the drive, Ubuntu cannot mount it (neither automatically nor otherwise). If there is, but it's damaged or (this is much less likely) of a type Ubuntu doesn't recognize, it will also not be mounted.
2. Unetbootin requires that the partition to which you write the contents of an `.iso` image be formatted FAT16 or FAT32. (And you should use FAT32 unless your image is tiny and you know you need to use FAT16.) Furthermore, it should be the first partition on the disk, and unless you really know what you're doing and know you need to do something differently, it should be the only partition on the disk and it should take up all the available space. Furthermore (though you don't usually have to do anything to make this the case), it should be a primary (not a logical) partition and the disk's partition table should be of type MSDOS.

If you have valuable data on your disk, then you shouldn't be writing an `.iso` image to it anyway, because that would destroy the data. Otherwise, you can safely address either or both of the above problems by creating a new partition table on the disk, and then creating a single partition, taking up all the available space, of type FAT32.

One easy way to do this is with the GParted Partition Editor, which is provided by the `gparted` package. You can install that package in the Software Center. Then run GParted. Select the drive in the drop-down menu at the upper-right corner of the GParted window. Make sure you've selected the correct drive--it would be bad to perform these data-destroying operations on the wrong disk!

Do Edit > Create Partition Table and accept the defaults. Then create a FAT32 partition, also with everything the default. This will make it a primary partition and as big as possible.

Then apply your changes by clicking the green check-mark. You can now mount the drive (or take it out and put it back in, and it should mount automatically). When GParted finishes, close out of it. Then you can write an .iso image to it with Unetbootin.

---

Alternatively, you might consider using a different method to write the `.iso` image to the drive, which would let you skip over formatting and mounting the drive.

You can use Startup Disk Creator for this purpose, as described in the [official installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

You can also use `dd` from the command-line. See [dd(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dd.1.html). If you have an `.iso` image called `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` and located in your Downloads folder, and if you would write its contents to `/dev/sdb1` in Unetbootin, then the corresponding `dd` command is:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dd if=ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

It's very important that you tell it to output to `/dev/sdb` (or whatever drive you want it on), **not** `/dev/sdb1` (i.e., not the first partition on the drive).

Comment: I was struggling for a while too, it was the filesystem format of the stick that kept it hidden. Formatting it to FAT32 solves the problem.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer. Why isn't it marked as accepted?

Comment: I am having this same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 and formatting the USB drive to FAT32 has no effect at all.

Answer (score 32):

I didn't get UNetbootin to list my USB drive, but you can force it to use a specific one if you know the device name:

```
unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdb1
```

You'll find out about your device number by listing all:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 starting up Unetbootin this way has no effect.

Comment: Works OK on 16... might also have something to do with UNetbootin version.

Comment: This allowed me to select my thumbdrive properly, I had to mount manually but that is ok.

Comment: Worked well in 16.04.01.

Comment: worked perfectly!!!!!! no time to read the wall of text in that first answer.

Comment: Best solution .

Answer (score 2):

I welcome you here!I think it is a common behavior by Ubuntu because the same I experienced on many occasions.What I do at these time that just click on `the drive` and open it in `Nautilus window`.Then come back to the particular application which need this drive.It is clearly described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount).Moreover,it is better to see this drive is displayed in File system>Media.

Comment: This has no effect on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I found that for me it happens when usb drive is labeled with non ASCII symbols. So try to change it to contain plain ASCII. Not sure about spaces, but it's always better to name it without spaces like `drive_8gb`.

It's possible to change label using `gparted` for example when drive is unmounted. Once I labeled it as described and reconnected it, unetbootin started to work well with the drive.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18) other advises already here did not help by themselves - renaming partition to ASCII characters only, formatting to FAT32, adding target in command line.

Helped changing drive in Unetbooting graphic interface from partition to drive, that is getting rid of '1' at the end in my case.

BTW, I did not see how I can add several ISO files to drive, and that is why I was trying to use it as advised here: [Multi-partition multi OS bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb)...

EDIT: the issue went away after re-creating partition table for USB stick in question, now Unetbooting works with partitions too (could not boot from resultant stick though...).