# How do I use Unetbootin to make a bootable Windows USB installer?

Tags: usb, windows-xp, unetbootin

it says missing bootmngr or something like that. I'm on ubuntu 12.04 or whatever, the newest one using the gparted to format to NTSC and then unetbootin to install the bootloader, and the iso, then restart. also, i do not know how to use terminal or code..and im also using an external hardrive because this laptop is missing one...

Comment: 1.12.04/2.NTFS/3. I did not undertand what is it that you did. You got the UBuntu ISO, burned it into the USB using Unetbootin..then what? Windows got messed and it says bootmgr is missing? that is fixed using the Windows CD not the Ubuntu USB..

Comment: no no, im on ubuntu, and i want to get rid of ubuntu and put windows on here. i put the windows iso on the usb drive, then the program tells me to restart. i do, and it says bootmngr missing.

Comment: Unetbootin in not intended for making bootable USBs with Windows. Use proper tools for the job, and proper help and support sites as well.

Comment: im on ubuntu! and all the guides i find use unetbootin. i thought this was a help site?

Comment: @JoeMech Give [MultiSystem](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://liveusb.info/dotclear/) a shot :)

Comment: @Nitin Venkatesh  it's almost 7 years later and MultiSystem has still never included Windows.

Answer (score 84):

That worked for me.

- **Format** your USB as **FAT32** in GParted
- Open UNetbootin and get it as far as the stage where it brings up the
  USB partition to install to e.g. `/dev/sdb1` — *Don't install the ISO,
  though*
- Leaving UNetbootin open as is, switch to GParted
- **Format** the USB in GParted as **NTFS**
- If GParted doesn't automatically add the "boot" flag, add it yourself
- Exit GParted, mount USB by running `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` (don't forget to replace `sdb1` with your one)
- Now, go back to UNetbootin, **which you've left open in the meantime**,
  and click OK

Doing so, UNetbootin will think you are using a FAT32 partition and will let you use NTFS format.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to do it from linux, not windows

Comment: I tried that but I get a "BOOTMGR is missing" message at boot.

Comment: Cool, a great way to get around newer versions of unetbootin not supporting NTFS.

Comment: What a great ugly dirty hack! But it's not your fault :) Thanks, worked very well!

Comment: Awesome hack :D Worked for me in **Ubuntu 12.04** with **Unetbootin 565-3**

Comment: a more elegent way with recent versions: `unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdd1` (for example).  This worked for me, YMMV.

Comment: I had a problem with an ACER desktop computer, the live USB only worked on some computers and I tried changing BIOS settings... In fact, you can directly format USB to NTFS and then copy paste ISO content on USB but in in my case, in order to work with the ACER desktop computer, I used Microsoft's tool "Windows 7 USB - DVD Tool.exe" through VirtualBox Windows VM.

Comment: god bless you angel.

Answer (score 2):

If Windows is what you're trying to install, then Windows 7 bootable USB DVD download tool from Microsoft (Also works on XP) allows you to create a bootable version of windows 7 OS for installing windows through USB drive. To download this utility click [Here](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe).

***Note: You need to run this on a windows machine.***

For more information see [Windows 7 USB Creator](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm)

> Now to create a bootable Windows 7 USB Drive while using Ubuntu, then
>   you need to make sure you have a Windows 7 .ISO file (you can create
>   it from the DVD) and a 4GB USB flash drive (or larger).
>
> Install Gparted and format the USB drive to NTFS. In Ubuntu, use the
>   following command to install Gparted:<sup>1</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

> To be able to format a drive to NTFS, you'll also need ntfs-3g -
>   install it using the following command:<sup>1</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Create A Bootable Windows 7 USB Drive From Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)</sup>

Updated to add the way to create it using Ubuntu from the Source.

Install Gparted and format the USB drive to NTFS. to install Gparted:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

To format the usb flash drive drive NTFS, install ntfs-3gt to install just type the command below in terminal

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

download TESTED Unetbootin version 494 from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/494/unetbootin-linux-494/download)

Once downloaded navigate to the folder where the file was downloaded, most likley the Downloads folder, and open terminal there.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux
sudo ./unetbootin-linux-494
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install unetbootin
```

Once installed.  open UNetbootin, select "Diskimage" and then browse for your Windows 7 ISO file.

Comment: Bit hard to run it on a Windows machine it you don't have one.

Comment: @mckenzm If you click on the last link, you will see how to create it using Ubuntu.  I will add  those steps in the answer.