# GNURadio Live CD installed on HDD adding persistence

Tags: live-cd, persistence, gnuradio

I installed gnu radio live cd on my hdd as a third OS on my laptop. Now I can boot in all three of them. But I want the Gnu radio to have persistence as in each time I boot it starts as a live OS.

Is it possible to add persistence right now or do I need to do a fresh ubuntu installation?

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of using a non-Ubuntu iso file or live CD, you can try like this: 1. Create an ubuntu 16.04.x (*maybe* it works in newer versions too) persistent live system or installed system, and 2. into that system install gnuradio with the commands  `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnuradio`

Comment: Actually, I wanted all the installed packages just like in the live cd . I know I could get all the packages list and install it on a fresh installation. Looking for shortcuts.. :sigh:
But my question remains the same, is there a way of making this current live cd installation like a regular installation/persistence I mean by adding some lines to the grub etc?


Thanks

Comment: Installing a LiveCD version and adding persistence to it rather than just fully installing it seems like a contradictory approach. It is possible to add persistence to a LiveISO via a secondary drive but the effort involved and the potential reliability issues isn't worth it in my opinion vs just installing the system directly.

Comment: Some people seem to find great joy in flagging valid questions off-topic **without doing any research**. The GNU Radio Live SDR Environment, produced by Corgan Labs, is a **bootable Ubuntu Linux DVD or USB drive image**, with GNU Radio and third party software pre-installed. ie **it is Ubuntu**.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron So it is a custom Ubuntu derivative, not an official flavour supported by Canonical. See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @Melebus: It is  **Third Party Software**, thus On-Topic. It can be added to Vanilla Ubuntu using: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.7", "sudo apt install gnuradio". see: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR#Ubuntu_PPA_Installation

Comment: @Melebus et al: Gnu Radio Companion is available from Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 0):

### Options for Multiple Persistence

You can add up to 4GB persistence by adding a casper-rw file and 4GB more adding a home-rw file, (re-labeled casper-rw file), to the gnu radio partition root. You will need to add the word persistent to your grub.cfg file along with the persistent-path to these files, (or to syslinux.cfg or txt.cfg if booting using Syslinux).

You can not have multiple Persistent partitions on a drive.

If you want multiple Persistent installs on the HDD, try YUMI, The persistent casper-rw files are of unlimited size if you are booting BIOS, They are limited to 4GB if you are using the UEFI version of YUMI.

You can also create multiple Full installs on HDD, by installing to multiple partitions, each as you would to internal drive. They will have unlimited persistence. Good to start with a GPT partition table as you can fit more partitions.

Ref: ["Handmade" live usb multisystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183191/handmade-live-usb-multisystem/1184111#1184111) or [Multi-partition multi OS bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/1076379#1076379) and [Install grub on a multi-partition and multiboot USB flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097919/install-grub-on-a-multi-partition-and-multiboot-usb-flash-drive/1098055#1098055)