# dual boot flash drive

Tags: live-usb

I am getting tired of carrying around multiple flash drives for different startup options. Is there a way that I can create an AVG rescue CD and Ubuntu on a flash drive and have both of them show for me to select while booting?

Comment: I use a larger flash drive with a full install of grub. Then add many ISO and use grub2's loopmount to boot many other systems. I like gparted, parted rescue, knoppix, Boot-Repair, maybe another Ubuntu or two versions, depending on size of flash drive.  Is your system UEFI or BIOS, or maybe you want both. I prefer not to try to do both UEFI & BIOS as keeping it in sync can be an issue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257100&p=13188883#post13188883 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484 Not sure if AVG is bootable as ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Get a flash drive that has enough space for both installations (at least 16gb)

Install Ubuntu and while installing, make 2 partitions (1 for Ubuntu and for for AVG)

After installing Ubuntu with Grub, install AVG on the other partition