# How to create a dual-boot pen-drive supporting UEFI and Legacy BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-legacy

How to create a Hy-bride boot mode pen-drive which can support both UEFI Mode and Legacy BIOS mode?
When we create a USB stick with UEFI mode which can't run in Legacy BIOS mode, and when we create a USB stick with Legacy BIOS mode that also unable to run in UEFI mode.
why I want both BOOT MODE?
1)for security :- I want to fix some problems or remove viruses--- for that I use [bitdefender-rescue-cd.iso](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/2013/bitdefender-rescue-cd.iso) in UEFI mode.(But not run in Legacy mode.)/
2)For surfing :- Multi_boot USB which have both boot loader.
Also I was try **YUMI**(for making bitdefender-rescue-cd in UEFI) and **Unetbootin**(for making Linux_mint17.1_live_cd in Legacy) combined and I was successfully copy data into USB but only UEFI mode is Working.

 Is it any way to make or Copy Legacy or UEFI boot loader manually?

Comment: See these: Flash drive to boot in UEFI or BIOS - sudodus
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS AND:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Ubuntu_single_boot_in_UEFI_mode
A new and so far successful attempt to create a stable portable system, that works in UEFI and BIOS mode
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213631&p=13262506#post13262506  AND:
http://spblinux.de/blog/2013/06/uefi-and-bios-bootable-usb-stick-with-grub2/

Comment: I have not tried both from one flash drive, as I have too many flash drives. But I do with either UEFI or BIOS directly install grub and put ISO on flash drive. Then manually edit grub to use its loopmount boot to directly boot ISO. Has worked for BIOS or UEFI for me. And then one somewhat larger flashdrive with many ISO. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot AND:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also have a Laptop whose motherboard BIOS supports both Legacy and UEFI Boot options.

I use [RUFUS](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) as a utility to create bootable media for both Linux and Windows platforms.
It has options such as **Partition scheme and target system type** which creates the bootable media for below mentioned types.

1. MBR Partition scheme for BIOS (Legacy) and UEFI
2. MBR Partition scheme for UEFI
3. GPT Partition scheme for UEFI

And also for specific type of ISO files supported with EFI-CSM , the utility is able to create bootable media accordingly.

To create a bootable USB that supports both *Legacy* and *UEFI* Boot options proceed as follows.

1. Open Rufus utility.
2. Select the USB drive onto which you want to create the live bootable media.
3. In order to support both UEFI and Legacy boot select the first option i.e **MBR Partition scheme for BIOS and UEFI** under partition scheme and target system type.
4. Select file system as FAT32 and Default Cluster size.
5. Tick the box with ***Create a bootable disk using*** and browse for the ISO file.
6. Click *START* and wait for it to complete.

After completion boot the USB on any PC and you will see that it provides option to boot through LEGACY and also through UEFI.

(**NOTE:** Ensure that your BIOS settings have been set to allow Legacy Boot options and not strictly UEFI.)[image]

Here is a picture of how it works.!
[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't truly support both BIOS and UEFI as the solution requires configuring the PC to use legacy BIOS emulation

Comment: @HairOfTheDog is correct. On an Intel NUC 11, which does not support legacy BIOS booting at all (no CSM option), rufus-created "dual mode" drives are not visible!

Answer (score 0):

### Rufus Persistent Pendrive install

That works with both BIOS and UEFI

Rufus does an OK job of installing Ubuntu Live to USB.
It works with both BIOS and UEFI.
It does not do Pesistent installs out of the box.

Many people prefer a Persistent pendrive that will save changes.

- Create a Live pendrive using Rufus.
- Create a casper-rw file:

  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of =casper-rw bs=1M count=512

  sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw

(where count=512 is persistence size, with max 4GB).

- Move the new casper-rw file to the root of the Live Pendrive.
- Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, add a space and the word "persistent" after quiet splash ---.
- Drive will now be persistent.

*Casper-rw partitions do not work with Rufus.