# Install from installed OS

Tags: boot

I have a USB that I have installed Ubuntu on, not the USB installer package.  I would still like to be able to install Ubuntu on other systems using this drive however.  Problem is the 'Install Ubuntu' icon disappears once it's installed somewhere...

Is there any easy way to get it back?  The installer?

Comment: Well, when you installed Ubuntu on the drive, you wiped the contents of it as a LiveCD. I would try creating a partition on the drive that is a LiveCD, and add it to Grub.

Comment: I have several full installs, but create another partition (not required) and put many ISO in that /ISO partition, can be folder or in /boot. Then from grub directly boot the ISO.  I think this is more just grub booting ISO, but similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484 and this from any install with link to many examples to boot various ISO: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your definition of "easy":

1. is there a 1 second solution of pointing you to the right executable and presto, it's back?
   **Sorry, no**
2. Can you download the ISO again onto your existing partition and boot from that?
   **Sorry, no**
3. Can you:

   1. Download the ISO again
   2. Burn it to another USB
   3. Boot that USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode to repartition your first USB to have enough space to contain the second USB
   4. Boot the primary USB and `dd` the second USB onto the partition of your first USB
   5. Add the second partition on your primary USB to the grub menu
      **Well, yes!**

But then, you might as well stop at #3.2. and just use 2 USBs: one to install and one to use.

#### And that's the easiest solution!  ;-)

Comment: Please don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**