# Loading Gparted Live ISO from Grub 2 gives "disk not found" error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to extend my Ubuntu partition by shrinking down my Windows partition. Using Windows Disk Management Tool I've shrinked out 99.67 Gb and now I have it unallocated. I need to add this 99.67 Gb to my Ubuntu root partition.

I'm using GParted and following [this tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847).

Here's what the `df` command prints out:

```
➜  ~ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1951080       12   1951068   1% /dev
tmpfs             392684     1040    391644   1% /run
/dev/sda8       50264772 45937836   1750552  97% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1963416        0   1963416   0% /run/shm
none              102400       32    102368   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1          98304    29567     68737  31% /boot/efi
shmfs            4194304  1162184   3032120  28% /dev/shm
```

so it seems that my Ubuntu root partition is `sda8`.

So, according to the tutorial, in file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` I add the new menuentry. Here's how this file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "GParted Live ISO" {
    set isofile="/denis/iso/gparted-live-0.27.0-1-i686.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,8)$isofile
    linux (loop)/vmlinuz boot=live config union=aufs noswap noprompt ip=frommedia findiso=$isofile toram=filesystem.squashfs
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

However, I get this error when trying to boot "GParted Live ISO" from Grub:
[image]
and when I press any key to exit, Windows immediately starts to boot.

The iso file `gparted-live-0.27.0-1-i686.iso` is located in `/home/denis/iso/` directory.

---

Could you please help me to find out what I'm doing wrong here and how to correctly load my GParted Live image from iso?

## Update 1

I've investigated a bit and found the location for my iso file in `/boot` folder from grub, it's `(hd1,gpt8)/`. Here's the screenshot from Grub console:
[image]

Here's how my new `40_custom` menuentry looks like:

```
menuentry "GParted Live ISO" {
    set isofile="/boot/iso/gparted-live-0.27.0-1-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop (hd1,gpt8)$isofile
    linux (loop)/vmlinuz boot=live config union=aufs noswap noprompt ip=frommedia findiso=$isofile toram=filesystem.squashfs
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

When I boot "GParted Live ISO" menuentry, I receive the following output:
[image]

Comment: sda8 should correspond to 'hd0,7', as `df` counts partitions from 1, grub does from 0.

Comment: `set isofile="/home/denis/iso/gparted-live-0.27.0-1-i686.iso"`

Comment: @ridgy this gives me the exact save error except now it says `disk 'hd0,7' not found`

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Partitions really count from 1...

Comment: @ridgy do you have any other ideas on why this error is happening?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just burn the iso to a disk or usb drive and set your system to boot from that.

Comment: I typically keep my / partition small. So I have another partition just for ISO. Partition number and path are the major issues, I still often have to correct my entries. http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484 IF your system is UEFI, you also need to be using the 64 bit version of gparted.

Comment: @oldfred I've changed my ISO file to the 64 bit version, as you've advised. And I've also corrected the path and now I get another error. Please, see the Update 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's how I finally got this working:

```
menuentry 'GParted 64-bit ISO' {
  set gfxpayload=text # ~= vga='normal'
  set isofile_abspath='/boot/iso/gparted-live-0.27.0-1-amd64.iso'
  set isofile_devpath="${devroot}${isofile_abspath}"
  loopback loop "(${root})${isofile_abspath}"
  linux '(loop)/live/vmlinuz' boot='live' union='overlay' username='denis' config components noswap noeject toram='filesystem.squashfs' ip='' nosplash findiso="${isofile_abspath}"
  initrd '(loop)/live/initrd.img'
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. $root is not defined and $devroot is not used?

Comment: This doesn't work. The grub error is the following: `error: out of memory.`, then `error: no server is specified.` and then `error: you need to load the kernel first.`