# How to add unallocated space to root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, parted

I need to add unallocated space to my root ext4 partition where my Ubuntu 14.04 is installed.

I've read dozens of tutorials and couldn't find the one working for me.

Most of the tutorials include using the `extended` partition and moving space left to right or right to left. I don't really understand any of these terms and I'm not able to create an extended partition from my unallocated space.

If I click "Create new Partition" on my unallocated space, I'm only allowed to create it as a 'Primary Partition'.

It is also not possible to boot from live cd as I'm using Grub 2 that somehow does not allow me to boot from iso file and just gives me errors when I try to do so. I've already posted a question about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/857250/480945) and it seems there's no answer.

So, anyway, I need to extend my root partition when it is mounted (I've read that runtime extending can be done without losing the data).

Here's my GParted window screenshot:
[image]
My root partition is `dev/sda8`. It sometimes shows a mount point like on the picture (`/,/var/lib/docker/aufs`) and sometimes like this: `/` (don't really know why).

---

Could anyone please explain to me how I can add my unallocated space to the `/dev/sda8` partition (in the most simple words possible, step-by-step for an absolute dummy in all this)?

PS: maybe it will be safer to extend my partition from Windows?

#### Update

```
➜  ~ sudo parted -l /dev/sda
Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPKX-8 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot
 2      106MB   1050MB  944MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 3      1050MB  1184MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1184MB  285GB   284GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
10      285GB   301GB   16,1GB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      301GB   301GB   369MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 6      301GB   571GB   270GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      676GB   729GB   52,4GB  ext4
 7      729GB   750GB   21,5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: Is this an MBR or GPT partition table? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sda`. Also, I don't think it's actually possible to resize while mounted, and even if it is, it is certainly not advisable. You should do this from a live system. You don't need grub at all for that, just change the boot order in your EFI settings or BIOS to boot from USB or CD, wherever you burn your ISO to. Alternatively, just do it from Windows where your `/` won't be mounted.

Comment: @terdon If I do that from Windows, the data will not be lost (most likeky), is that right?

Comment: It shouldn't, no. Always make a backup, of course, but resizing unmounted disks usually works with no problem. Your partition table is the newer, GPT format. This means you don't need (and can't have) extended partitions. That's why you saw no such option. You still can't do this with your mounted partition though.

Comment: You've made clear quite a bunch of things for me, thanks for that! I'll try to resize my partitions from Windows then