# How do I properly mount fat32 flash drive for Multisystem use?

Tags: mount, dolphin, fat32, udisks, multisystem

I'm attempting to switch to MultiSystem from YUMI so I can add ISOs to a multi-bootable flash drive with Ubuntu instead of Windows, and boy, am I starting to regret it.

- First, I backed up my flash drive to my internal drive.
- Using the Disks tool, I format the entire drive (MBR/DOS) and create a single labeled partition of type FAT32.
- I mount by selecting my drive in my file explorer, then try to use the Multisystem script but the list of drives is empty. Multisystem says it's looking in /media , but that's where it's mounted (/media/myname/drivelabel
- I try running Multisystem from the console as root, but it fails with error "Not root!". Oddly, when I run it normally (as my own user) I don't get that message. (I later suspect this is a mistranslated "don't run as root!", perhaps?)
- I give up on that method and try other avenues, such as burning the Multisystem-preinstalled ISO onto the drive instead, to no avail.
- I try mounting the drive before running the script, using my file manager.

I get an error in both Dolphin and Nautilus:

```
An error occurred while accessing 'CPDmulti', the system responded:
The requested operation has failed: Error mounting system-managed
device /dev/sdc1: Command-line `mount "/media/CPDmulti"' exited
with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'fat32'
```

- That's weird. Shouldn't FAT32 be universally readable? I do some research and try `umount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/drivelabel` which works. However, it still doesn't show in the list.
- I try to mount manually in a /media/ directory subfolder instead of the /media/username/ directory subfolder.
- This works! Apparently, Multisystem can't handle the normal /media/username convention and needs it mounted right in /media...
- Multisystem fails to continue. `Error: Do you have write permission in this folder?: /media/CPDmulti`...
- I check, and it's right - I can't write in the folder. I try all the `chmod` and `chown` tricks I know, but the mount command always makes it read-only. I can't mount as my own user, either, only root can mount.
- After research I learn that the graphical environments use `udisks2` to do their mounting, which firsts mounts as root, then gives the created mount folder permissions to be accessed by the user. That's how it get around the above.
- So I try to invoke it myself: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1` and whaddaya know.

I get this again:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed:
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: 
Command-line `mount "/media/CPDmulti"' exited 
with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: unknown filesystem type 'fat32'
```

- Gah! How can I pass it the that `vfat` workaround? I try various versions of `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1 -t vfat` which checks out with the help text. Doesn't change anything, though.

In summary, while I obviously need a way to get this script working, my more general problem is that I can't seem to naturally mount fat32 volumes. What if I need to read a FAT flash drive? This is Kubuntu 17.04. Have I found a bug, or is there something I'm missing?

Online I see solutions to `mount: unknown filesystem type 'vfat'` but nobody really has the `mount: unknown filesystem type 'fat32'` problem (wheras `vfat` works fine for me). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that much work, you can just do your own multiple boot ISO system by installing grub and editing grub.cfg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484

Comment: @olfred True, I should learn to do the grub manually, but A) I want to use this script so I can easily update it anytime I want to add an ISO;  B) I want this GUI working for other people I give Ubuntu to, not just experts and C) My question potentially is about a bug, which would need to be solved either way.

Comment: You can also try this software, MultiBootUSB, that you find via http://multibootusb.org/

Comment: Yes, @sudodus, I eventually found that software. It's exactly what I wanted! Occasionally throws off some distros for having non-default directory structure, but it works for many others.