# Create Multiboot USB with a live USB stick

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

I have a live usb stick with ubuntu 20.04 LTS in it. I want to try out other distributions too. Is it possible to change it to a multiboot usb without formatting it? I tried with `ventoy`, but it is not working because the usb is partitioned into the bootable disk and writable portion.

Comment: maybe a stupid idea, but can you install multiple OS's on a usb stick and connect them via a single grub, also located on the usb stick?

Comment: You need to investigate Ventoy a little more, Just dragging and dropping multiple ISO's onto the disk works for me. The filesystem is exFAT which only works, out of the box, with Ubuntu 20.04 and later. However exFAT access can be installed in earlier versions. The FAT partition on the disk is only 32MB, the exFAT partition should take up the rest of the disk. YUMI is another good multiboot system. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-partition multi OS bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb)